# How did WWII change the GDPs of the great empires of the world?

Tags: world-war-two, economy, british-empire

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_empires#Largest_empires_by_economy) some of the greatest European empires seemed to peak in GDP in 1938. I assume that it was WWII that caused declines in the GDPs of these empires. If this indeed the case, then how exactly did WWII affect these countries imperialism to cause this GDP drop? And if this is not the case, then what DID affect these countries imperialism to cause this GDP drop?

Comment: Well, it definitively didn't help Germany, that's for sure.

Comment: AFAIK, there was only one "empire" at the start of WW2 - namely the British Empire, and it too decreased rapidly after WW2 as a result of decolonization. So, which "empires" are you talking about?

Comment: I don't think they peak in those years, those are just the years of measurement.  If I'm right, that would distort the analysis.  And I believe, to answer @taninamdar question, that the reason you're using "Empire" rather than "country" is only because the wikipedia page does so?

Comment: @taninamdar The UK wasn't the only one. Germany, France and the Netherlands also had quite significant overseas territories in Africa and SE Asia.

Comment: @Schwern I haven't heard them being termed as empires. Btw, which overseas territory did Germany have?

Comment: @taninamdar An empire is a conglomeration of nations. The Dutch, French, German and British Empires were specifically colonial or imperial where one nation controls others. In 1939 the Dutch had [the Dutch East Indies and Caribbean holdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_Empire#Decolonization_.281942.E2.80.931975.29). The French had [significant African, Asian and South American holdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_colonial_empire#/media/File:Vichy_france_map.png). My mistake about Germany, their empire was wiped out in WWI.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion..... The Economy of USA rose because of the second world war. USA lent money to different countries during the war. Not only Money but other resources. So After the WW2 the countries returned the money to the usa..making them richer than the rest(in that period)`..just my idea

Comment: Please consult [ask]; H:SE isn't really designed for opinions; we;re looking more for historical scholarship. Welcome to the site.